# URL shortener for Arabic

Tags: gratis, web-apps, url-shortening

What is a recommended web app for URL shortener in other languages, e.g. based on the Arabic alphabet? I want that because lots of English characters aren't pronouncable in other languages. Ideally all languages that are readibly used there shouldn't be that many I think.

The software should be free, and can be self-hosted or a web-app already available online.

The following is the shortest URL shortener but the URLs are not typable depedent on the languages: http://asiajin.com/blog/2009/09/29/the-world-shortest-url-shortener-using-international-domain-name/

Comment: @LiamWilliam could you please [edit] your question and include the "must-have language/character sets"? Keep in mind, as you've already pointed out, that using language specific character sets might make it difficult to impossible to type the results in other areas (e.g. Arabic wouldn't do easily for most people in Japan or England, Japanese not in Mexico, etc.)

Comment: @Izzy It is now for Arabic only although I'm not sure for what languages it might exist.  If this gets attention we can ask the question for other languages.